# Can I filter objects in forms.ManyToManyField to equal value selected in another field?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I want to set a queryset on a ManyToManyField to get all objects that have a ForeignKey equal to ForeignKey set in another formfield.

```
class ProductAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['variants'].queryset = Variant.objects.filter(variantCategory__productCategory__name_single='test')
```

This works, It selects all "Variant"'s where value of "name_single" of productCategory in its variantCategory is equal to 'test'. I want to replace 'test' to be equal to "name_equal" of productCategory set in this very form.

Here is some code to ilustrate how the objects relate to eachother.

```
class Variant(models.Model):
    variantCategory = models.ForeignKey('VariantCategory')

class VariantCategory(models.Model):
    productCategory = models.ForeignKey('ProductCategory')

class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    name_single = models.CharField()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTOno.jpg

This shows the field that should define the productCategory to equal to.

I realize this is kind of hard to explain, if any of you need extra code/info let me know!

Also, I just need the query to get all objects where productCategory equals to another productCategory. The "name_equal" part doesn't really matter, could be the id of the object to!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use instance from "form".

Try something like this.

```py
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.fields['variants'].queryset = Variant.objects.select_related('variantCategory__productCategory').filter(variantCategory__productCategory_id=self.instance.productCategory_id)
```

This solution won't work if you add new Product, because you won't have instance (instance will be only on memory, not database) so you couldn't match foreign_key. As u can see i added select_related. Bellow some good practice

- remember to use **select_related**:

  ```
  Variant.objects.select_related('variantCategory__productCategory').filter(variantCategory__productCategory_id=instance.productCategory_id)
  ```
- use model_id instaed of model.id

  Variant.objects.select_related('variantCategory__productCategory').filter(variantCategory__productCategory_id=instance.productCategory_id)

---

If you just need the query to get all objects where productCategory equals to another productCategory try this:

```
myProductCategory = ProductCategory.objects.last()
Product.objects.filter(productCategory__id=myProductCategory.id)
```

Let me know if it works :)